# Hashicorp Vault get Vault to generate several key values

Tags: java, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm using Hashicorp Vault and java spring vault, trying to generate several key-value pairs. What is the best way (or vault API) to do this? Ideally this key-value pair is generated within Vault.

Java will only have access (or need to know) to the key-part which is a reference to the real secret, the value-part.

**As an illustration:**
From java initalizeSecret() -> Vault creates key-value pair -> return key-part to java.

Comment: can you explain more what do you try to achieve? Do you want to insert secrets to vault? (using kv secrets)?

Comment: I want to create a key for a user. I don't need Java to know the real key, just initialize it. Yes using KV secret engine.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I fully understand - do you try to generate a vault token for a user in your system? (see auth methods options - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/index.html ) or do you try to save a user password in vault? (not suggested - vault is for saving secrets - db passwords, api token etc... and not user passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you have to supply the key to write it to vault. Vault itself does not generate your key. You must know the key so you will use it to read this value afterwords.